# check if the file exists in two path

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, copy, continuous-integration

I need to check whether the files exist in two path.
For eg(consider C:\D\a.txt && D:\E\a.txt).

a.txt files exist in both Dir I need to perform copy operation.

```
@echo OFF 
IF EXIST C:\D\a.txt == D:\E\a.txt
copy C:\D\a.txt F:\test\a.txt
```

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: your syntax needs a small change, just check with `IF EXIST` for both files: `IF EXIST \d1\a.txt IF EXIST \d2\a.txt COPY \d1\a.txt \d2\a.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are doing this on dos

```
if exist {insert file name here} (
    rem file exists
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```

Something like this maybe be useful

```
if exist C:\D\a.txt (
   set fileA=true
   )
if exist D:\E\a.txt (
   set fileB=true
   )
if %fileB% EQU %FileA% (
   Echo "The two file exist"
   ) else ( 
   Echo "Do something"
   )
```

Comment: If it is false one.How can i validate.Do you have any ideas

Comment: The "else" do it for you. If true print "The two files exist", else (false)print "Do something"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that two files are equal, use FC:

```
FC C:\D\a.txt D:\E\a.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 COPY C:\D\a.txt\ F:\test\filename.txt
```

`FC` means `FileCompare` and sets %ERRORLEVEL% to

- 0 it the files are equal
- 1 if they are different
- 2 if one of the files doesn't exist or is not readable
- -1 if you have a syntax error.

This means that you don't need to check whether the files are present using `IF EXIST`. If this is not the case `FC` will set `%ERRORLEVEL%` to `2` and the file won't be copied. It will only copy the file if both files exist AND are equal.

For more info on FC check http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html.

If you just want to ensure that both files exist use this:

```
IF EXIST C:\D\a.txt IF EXIST D:\E\a.txt COPY C:\D\a.txt\ F:\test\filename.txt
```